# Starting a script within a script - how do I fix /bin/sh: 1: filename.py: not found

Tags: python, linux, shell

I'm looking to control a script via Zigbee/XBee using X-CTU. I've created a script called `zb_control.py`. Now I'm trying to start and stop another script within this script. A script `adxl345test.py` is used to collect data from an attached accelerometer on my Raspberry Pi.

The idea behind the `zb_control.py` script is that I run it and then if I type "run" in X-CTU the script will start running `adxl345test.py` and collect data.

I'm trying to create a script within a script that can also be stopped again and then still have the `zb_control.py` running ready to recieve new input from X-CTU.

As you can tell I've tried different things:

```
import serial, time, sys, os, subprocess
from subprocess import check_call
from subprocess import call

while True:

    ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600,timeout=2)
    inc=ser.readline().strip()

    if inc=='run':
        print("---------------")
        print("Collecting data")
        print("---------------")
        p = subprocess.Popen("adxl345test.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        # p = call(["python", "adxl345test.py"])
        # p = os.system("python adxl345test.py")
        # p = execfile("adxl345test.py")
        # call(["python", "adxl345test.py"])

    elif inc=='stop':
        # check_call(["pkill", "-9", "-f", adxl345test.py])
        # serial.write('\x03')
        # os.system("pkill –f adxl345test.py")
        # call(["killall", "adxl345test.py"])
        p.kill()
        print("-----------------------")
        print("Script has been stopped")
        print("-----------------------")
```

I get this error while when I start the adxl345test.py script:

`/bin/sh: 1: adxl345test.py: not found`

How do I fix this error?

Comment: I think you need to mention the full path to 'adxl345test.py'

Comment: If the `adxl...` sscript is not in a directory mentioned in your `$PATH`, you need to pass this path explicitly (either relative or absolute)

Comment: `print("Collecting data”)` has a wrong ending quote (`RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`). Probably unrelated, but still an error.

Comment: Have you tried to add the `#!/usr/bin/python` thingie on the first line of the scripts? Replace that path with what ever is the real path to the python executable, do a `which python` to get it.

Comment: I added the full path /home/pi/adxl345test.py. However now I get the following error:

/bin/sh: 1: /home/pi/adxl345test.py: Permission denied

Comment: try running `chmod +x /home/pi/adxl345test.py`, this will add execution rights to your python script. Read up on permissions if you are unsure.

Comment: I got it to run and it's now collecting data properly. However now the problem is stopping the adxl345test.py again. As you can tell from the script from above I'm using p.kill() but the script doesn't stop collecting data. When I type "stop" in XCTU my zb_control.py does print the print commands but the p.kill() isn't being executed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using UNIX line endings in the external scripts.